# Chrome Audits: Datacamp in third-party code

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, styled-components, pagespeed

Recently I've discovered some weird stuff in Chrome Audits tool, and I have no idea what is going on.

[image: Datacamp in Chrome Audits tool]

Does anyone know what **Datacamp** stands for?

Comment: Check the Network tab in your Chrome dev tools while you load the page. Do you see any scripts being loaded that you don't recognize?

Comment: There is nothing suspicious. Google Analytics, GTM, vendor.js (482KB), app.js (166KB) and two scrips from GA (23.4KB and 1.4KB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you use CDN cdn77.
It is their second name.
Or some of scripts which you includes, use cdn77 for host some scripts.

https://www.peeringdb.com/org/19169

Comment: Yes, we use CDN77 for our assets. Interesting. Thank you!